# Div com background sobre uma div com opacity

Tags: css

Tenho duas divs:

```css
.containerBlock {
  opacity: 0.9;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
}

.containerCall {
  background: blue;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerBlock">
  <div class="containerCall">
    <h3>Título da DIV</h3>
    Detalhes do conteudo
  </div>
  ....
</div>
```

Meu problema é que a div `.containerCall` não está ficando com o background azul, me parece que ela está assumindo a transparência da `.containerBlock`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sNniffer/fpa1qb40/2/)

Comment: Afinal de contas, qual é a pergunta?

Comment: @AugustoVasques ué, não seria só ler a questão? "Meu problema é que a div .containerCall não está ficando com o background azul", está escrito

Comment: *..;Div com background sobre uma div com opacity...* e *...Meu problema é que a div .containerCall não está ficando com o background azul, me parece que ela está assumindo a transparência da .containerBlock...* isso não é pergunta é uma constatação do obvio. Qual o resultado pretende obter?

Comment: exato, como você mesmo disse, o problema da questão é Obvio, logo, a dúvida também. Se eu digo que meu problema é X, significa que a pergunta é referente ao problema. Obrigado, esta questão já foi solucionada.

Comment: Se julga ser uma boa solução não será eu quem o apresentara outro caminho. Passe bem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solucionei, removi a propriedade `opacity` e coloquei a transparência na cor do background desta forma: `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);`

```
.containerBlock {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 
  width:        100%;
  height:     100%; 
  z-index:    5; 
  position:     absolute;
}
```